# CSS Background - Contain but a bit smaller?

Tags: css

I think the answer is no, but...

Is there a way to say:

```
background-size: contain 90%
```

So it does exactly what `contain` would do, but a then adjust it a bit smaller?

Answer (score 3):

The ideal solution will be to have `padding: 10%` and add a div inside that contains the background image.
If you can't do that, try maybe with `:after` pseudo selector

Comment: I guess I a could reformat the image to have a bit of padding, also

Comment: with a background-color:white or any color for the padding, is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

You can consider `background-origin` and adjust either the border or the padding.

Example:

```css
.box {
  border:1px solid;
  height:200px;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800.jpg);
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-origin:content-box;
  padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Using border:

```css
.box {
  outline:1px solid;
  height:200px;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800.jpg);
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-origin:padding-box;
  border:15px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: this only works if the background-position is center.  If the background position is left center then this will  not work.

Comment: @JoshuaRobison the background-position doesn't matter. In all the cases, the image will not touch the padding or the border area (you can try all the combination)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with `background-size: contain;` and a percentage for `width` and `margin`:

```css
.background {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/600/400');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 90%; /* set width smaller than page */
  margin: 5%; /* add margin to make up difference */
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use another div wrapper your background div tag. Then using padding
Ex:

```
<div style="padding:10px">
    <div style="background:xxx;background-size: cover;width:100px;height:100px"></div>
</div>
```

You also can set

```
background-size: 90% 90%;
```